# In WPF project I don't see my user control in toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I added my User Control (dll-file) as reference in new WPF Project, but I can't see this control in Toolbox. What should I do to use my user control?

Comment: Pretty sure all you need to do is reference the namespace with the Control in your XAML. How is your control listed in the project references list?

Comment: Yes I rebuild. I added the dll of my User Control. And it viewed as other dlls in reference folder.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have this setting to true?

Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : AutoToolboxPopulate

If you do, you could also try this after building/rebuilding your user control project:
Right click Toolbox > Choose Items... > Browse > UserControl.dll

Comment: It works! Thank you. I added my control by using Tools>Options etc.

Comment: Sure thing. Mark this as the answer so people know where to look if they need it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your control have a parameterless constructor?

I had this problem when attempting to use a WPF control written by another member of my team. The only constructor was one with parameters. When I added a new constructor with no parameters the control appeared in the Toolbox.